# Display Data in different style on screen than that in Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

net and I need some help here:

In data base data is stored as

```
task   line_item   Amount

task1  lineitem1   amount
task2  lineitem2   amount
..
```

and I need to diplay it as

```
       line item1  lineitem 2  lineitem3
task1   amount     amount      amount
task2   amount     amount      amount 
..
```

is there good way to display and also to edit these field , so that changes get reverted to table.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: ASP.NET,WInforms,WPF,...? Where do you want to store it(f.e. GridView)? What dabase are you using? What DAL are you using(f.e. Entity Framework,LINQ-to-SQL, DataSet, ADO.NET)?

Comment: Yeah am trying to use it with grid view

Comment: ASP.NET-GridView? Add all missing informations to your question(technologies should be tagged).

Comment: database: oracle, I havnt started designing the page yet, am planning how to start.. will like to go with dataset and gridview .. any other good alternative will also be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just pulling data out of the db than I suggest creating an ObjectDataSource (ODS) and assign it to the gridview. Create your query in the DAL and bind it to the ODS.